# How to echo specific data from a row and column PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

So here is the way my database is setup

```
--------------------------------
|referral    |   message       |
--------------------------------
|1           |   hiiii         |
--------------------------------
```

referral is pretty much my way of saying "id" and message is what the user says. I am trying to echo out the message of referral 1 so it says "hiii" on the webpage. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: If you are using MySql this might help: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the following URL:-
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-with-php/

specifically:-

```
<?php
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','database_name')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
 $query = "SELECT message FROM table_name where referral=".intval($_REQUEST['id']);
 mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $row['message'] .'<br />';
 }
?>
```